# Laravel route names with params on a Resource

Tags: laravel, twig, laravel-5

Here are all my routes;

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function () {
    Route::resource('surveys', 'SurveyController');
    Route::resource('surveys/{survey}/groups', 'GroupController');
    Route::resource('surveys/{survey}/groups/{group}/questions', 'QuestionController');
});
```

This is one of my (many) defined routes;

```
METHOD = GET|HEAD
URI = admin/surveys/{survey}/groups/{groups}
Name = admin.surveys.{survey}.groups.show
Action = App\Http\Controllers\GroupController@show
```

How can I call this and pass in the group.id and the survey.id in my view (it is twig using twig_bridge if that matters)

I've tried;

```
{{ route('admin.surveys.{survey}.groups.show', ['survey' => survey.id, group.id]) }}
```

And other similar syntax but always get unexpected punctuation errors

I didn't name these routes myself. This is default Laravel when sticking to the naming conventions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the dot syntax to define nested resource routes:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function () {
    Route::resource('surveys', 'SurveyController');
    Route::resource('surveys.groups', 'GroupController');
    Route::resource('surveys.groups.questions', 'QuestionController');
});
```

Then you can route to them like this:

```
route('admin.surveys.groups.show', [$surveyId, $groupId])
route('admin.surveys.groups.questions.show', [$surveyId, $groupId, $questionId])
```